# Pandas performance slicing on Index vs slicing on Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, slice

I have a fairly large Pandas dataframe (30M rows) that I need to slice over and over so performance is crucial.
The slicing needs to be done over the value of one column and a list of values in the other column.
I tried two different approaches which can be illustrated with the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(1,1000,(10000000,4)),
    columns=['A','B','C','D']
).set_index(['A','B'])

# The values I'm looking for
index_a = np.random.randint(1,1000)  # One value
index_b = np.random.randint(1,1000,150)  # A list of values

# Slicing over the multi-index
idx = pd.IndexSlice
%timeit df.loc[idx[index_a, list(index_b)], :]

# Slicing over column values
df1 = df.reset_index()
%timeit df1.loc[(df1.A == index_a) & (df1.B.isin(index_b))]
```

On my machine the performance is really distinct for both scenarios:

Slicing over the index:

> 3.92 s ± 111 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Slicing over the columns:

> 2.15 s ± 77.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Slicing over the multi-index is much slower that slicing over the columns.

Is this the expected behavior? Is there a way to optimize the slicing process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving my problem grouping the data in one of the indexes, this increases the speed of the slicing more than 10 fold.
Example:

```
df_g = df.groupby(by='A')

def slice_it(ia, ib):
    tg = df_g.get_group(ia)
    return tg.loc[tg.B.isin(index_b)]

%timeit slice_it(index_a, index_b)
```